# I want to get a stream object from Azure Inheritance Iterator ItemPaged - ItemPaged[TableEntity] to Stream (Python). Is it possible?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I want to get a stream object from Azure Inheritance Iterator ItemPaged - ItemPaged[TableEntity] to stream (Python). Is it possible?

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-core/azure.core.paging.itempaged?view=azure-python
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-core/azure.core.paging.itempaged?view=azure-python

**#Updated 11.08.2021**
I have a realization to backup Azure Tables to Azure Blob - [Current process to backup Azure Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL4Ro.png). But I want to improve this process and I am considering different options. I try to get the stream from Azure Tables to use create_blob_from_stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to stream bytes from the HTTP response, and not the use the iterator of objects you receive.

Each API in the SDK supports a keyword argument call `raw_response_hook` that gives you access to the HTTP response object, and then let you use a stream download API if you want to. Note that since the payload is considered to represent objects, it will be pre-loaded in memory no matter what, but you can still use a stream syntax nonetheless.

The callback is simply one parameter:

```
def response_callback(response):
    # Do something with the response
    requests_response = response.internal_response
    # Use "requests" API now
    for chunk in requests_response.iter_content():
        work_with_chunk(chunk)
```

Note that this is pretty advanced, you may encounter difficulties and this might not fit what you want precisely. We are working on a new pattern on SDK to simplify complex scenario like that, but it's not shipped yet. You would be able to send and receive raw requests using a `send_request` method, which gives you absolute control on all aspect of the query, like explaining you just want to stream (no pre-load in memory) or disabling the deserialization by default.

Feel free to open an issue on the Azure SDK for Python repo if you have additional questions or clarification: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

*Edit with new suggestions:* `TableEntity` is a dict like class, so you can `json.dumps` as string, or `json.dump` as a stream while using the `ItemPaged<TableEntity>`. If JSON dumps raise an exception, you can try our JSON encoder in `azure.core.serialization.AzureJSONEncoder`: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/1ffb583d57347257159638ae5f71fa85d14c2366/sdk/core/azure-core/tests/test_serialization.py#L83

(I work at MS in the Azure SDK for Python team.)

Ref:

- https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content
- https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-core/1.17.0/azure.core.pipeline.policies.html#azure.core.pipeline.policies.CustomHookPolicy

Comment: Thank you very much @laurent for the information. I have updated more information in my question. Perhaps you have already encountered a similar need and could suggest the best solution to solve my question? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can put your voice to this issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/19926? It seems the service team is recommending azCopy right now for Tables backup. I will also edit with different ideas.